# Number of paths from a grid corner to visit all other points on a grid

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given an $m \times n$ grid of integer coordinates, how many paths can one start from a corner, say $(0, 0)$, and visit all other points? A path can end on any point.

For a start, I wrote a small script to traverse all possible paths of a $2 \times n$ grid. If only horizontal and vertical moves to neighboring points are allowed, the number of all possible paths seems to be $n$.

I extended the program a little bit to cover 8-connectivity i.e. a path can move diagonally. For $n$ from 1 to 9, the numbers of paths from my calculation are 1, 6, 20, 72, 240, 800, 2624, 8576, and 27904 (not in OEIS). All paths of a $2 \times 5$ grid are as follows. (Red dots indicate starting corner points.)

[image: Paths of 2x5 grid]

I did some quick searches on the problem. [Self-avoiding walk](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-AvoidingWalk.html) seems to point to the right direction and there is probably no closed-form solution. However, all the examples in the reference and [all sequences on OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=self-avoiding) frame the problem as the number of paths given a fixed length or given starting and ending nodes. I am not sure whether the 8-connectivity case is considered as self-avoiding either.

Comment: You may be interested in graph theory elements. If the starting point wasn't fixed, the number you are looking for is the number of Hamiltonian paths in a king's graph. Here is the sequence of square grids: http://oeis.org/A158651

Comment: from the example you give, it seems that you are considering that the steps $(\Delta x ,  \Delta y)$ might only be in $[-1,1]^2 \ (0,0)$, is it so ?

Comment: @GCab Yes, any consecutive pair in the path must be neighbors.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answers for the $n \times 2$ grid:

Without diagonal moves allowed, note that there's exactly one path ending in each row, so there are $n$ paths.

With diagonal moves allowed, classify paths as follows:

- Paths ending in the top row. It's easy to see that there are $2^{n-1}$ such paths.
- Paths whose first moves visit rows 1, 2 in that order (2 routes), followed by an arbitrary path in rows 2 through $n$.
- Paths whose first moves visit rows 2, 1, 2, 3 in that order (4 routes), followed by an arbitrary path in rows 3 through $n$.

This yields the recurrence $x_{n+2}=2^{n+1}+2x_{n+1}+4x_n$, so we have

$$
\begin{pmatrix} x_{n+1} \\ x_{n+2} \\ 2^{n+1} \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\4&2&2\\0&0&2 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x_n \\ x_{n+1} \\ 2^n \end{pmatrix}
$$

so $x_n$ is the first element of
$
\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\4&2&2\\0&0&2 \end{pmatrix}^{n-1}
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\6\\2 \end{pmatrix}
$.

You can [efficiently exponentiate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) this matrix to compute values of $x_n$, or [diagonalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) it to obtain a [closed-form solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%281%29%3D1%2C+f%282%29%3D6%2C+f%28n%2B2%29%3D2%5E%28n%2B1%29%2B2f%28n%2B1%29%2B4f%28n%29).